# why we use SOAP and REST Protocols even though without SOAP and REST web applications work fine

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

The question is, why we use SOAP and REST or any other communication protocl for Webservices. I am looking for the answer to get. I am confuse here because without SOAP and REST we can communicate to web applications based on what we read in our books. For example, HTTP, TCP/IP, SMTP and many other protocols work good in providing communication between applications then what for we use SOAP and REST alongwith HTTP etc to build communications between applications. Waiting for someone to answer. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use SOAP for webservices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166746/why-use-soap-for-webservices)

Answer (score 0):

Web services(SOAP/Rest) enable any-to-any integration, supporting any programming language, any runtime platform, and any network transport.
With help of web service it's easy to communicate b/w two or more applications doesn't meter both are build in different language platform, Consumers of a Web Service do not need to know anything about the platform, object model, or programming language used to implement the service; they only need to understand how to send and receive data.